# Where can I find a complete list of acceptable pandas.Timestamp format?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, datetime-format, python-datetime

I find that pandas.Timestamp is extremely powerful and flexible parsing tool that accepts a wide range of timestamp/datetime formats. E.g.

```py
In [38]: pd.Timestamp('2020')
Out[38]: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')

In [39]: pd.Timestamp('2020-02')
Out[39]: Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00')

In [40]: pd.Timestamp('2020Q1')
Out[40]: Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
```

But it doesn't always do the "magic" I was expecting, e.g. the followings are illegal:

```py
In [41]: pd.Timestamp('202003')  # expecting 2020-03-01
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

In [42]: pd.Timestamp('2020H2')  # expecting 2020-07-01, i.e. 2020 second half (start)
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

I tried to find a complete list of supported formats but it seems that the document is missing (or I'm missing something). Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use quarters if looking into annual periods

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2020-Q1']})
pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq='Q').to_timestamp()
```

and for dates

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('202003', format='%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.timestamp()` is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is interchangeable with it in most cases.  Datetime library accepts ISO 8601 date formats.

In Python ISO 8601 date is represented in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm` format. For example, May 18, 2022, is represented as `2022-05-18T11:40:22.519222`.

- `YYYY`: Year in four-digit format
- `MM`: Months from 1-12 DD: Days from 1 to 31
- `T`: It is the separator character that is to be printed between the
  date and time fields. It is an optional parameter having a default
  value of “T”.
- `HH`: For the value of minutes
- `MM`: For the specified value of minutes
- `SS`: For the specified value of seconds
- `mmmmmm`: For the specified microseconds

> *[Source](https://pynative.com/python-iso-8601-datetime/)*

Directly from the Pandas documentation (*[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)*):

> There are essentially three calling conventions for the constructor. The primary form accepts four parameters. They can be passed by position or keyword.
>
> The other two forms mimic the parameters from datetime.datetime. They
> can be passed by either position or keyword, but not both mixed
> together.

### **Examples**

Using the primary calling convention:
This converts a datetime-like string

```
>>> pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01T12')
Timestamp('2017-01-01 12:00:00')
```

This converts a float representing a Unix epoch in units of seconds

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(1513393355.5, unit='s')
Timestamp('2017-12-16 03:02:35.500000')
```

This converts an int representing a Unix-epoch in units of seconds and for a particular timezone

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(1513393355, unit='s', tz='US/Pacific')
Timestamp('2017-12-15 19:02:35-0800', tz='US/Pacific')
```

Using the other two forms that mimic the API for datetime.datetime:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 12)
Timestamp('2017-01-01 12:00:00')

>>> pd.Timestamp(year=2017, month=1, day=1, hour=12)
Timestamp('2017-01-01 12:00:00')
```